# How to access remote .SVN with TortoiseSVN

Tags: svn, .htaccess, tortoisesvn

I just started working on a new project that already contains a .svn folder and respective files on a remote server. The previous developer obviously used this file to monitor the file changes however:

The .svn is in the public www but a .htaccess forwards all commands to a different directory.

How do I go about figuring out the correct URI to enter into tortoise to be able to access this .svn?

Thx

EDIT: I need to know the URI so that I can browse the repo. The repo is stored on the file system at www/.svn however when I type in http://www.mysite.com/.svn it gives me a warning

"Repository moved permanently to 'http://www.mysite.com/.svn/*; please relocate"

I believe that this is caused by the .htaccess in www/ redirecting all traffic.

Comment: It's very strange that you have a `.svn` in the URL, it should be typically `http://<server>/svn/<repository name>`. I think that your best option is to ask your project leader what the URL is instead of trying to guess or asking on this site.

Comment: Or, as asked by many of us below, what is the URL when you open the repo-browser on your local project folder, or if you check its properties? You can also find it from looking into the `.svn/entries` file, but that's a more desparate option ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a guess, could you open the .svn folder and check for files inside it, I am sure there must be some entry pointing to the correct URL

Comment: There are many files within this folder - could you point me towards what I might be looking for?

Comment: Is there an entries file in the .svn folder? It iwll have the url most of the time

Comment: alright there is an entries file and it contains a url however it does not match its current location on the site - does this mean it was moved and therefor does not apply any longer?

Comment: No need to mess inside the .svn folders to find the url: right-click on folder, choose "properties" from the context menu (the explorer one, not the one from the TSVN submenu), go to the subversion tab. The url is shown there.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean that the URL has changed since then, and if you really want to keep the working copy already present on your workstation, you can use the TortoiseSVN `Relocate` command at the root of the project. Then you will have to do an update, to make sure you're up to date with the server.

But it is rather advised to start a new, clean working copy with a checkout, rather than using an existing one.

> The .svn is in the public www but a
>   .htaccess forwards all commands to a
>   different directory.
>
> How do I go about figuring out the
>   correct URI to enter into tortoise to
>   be able to access this .svn?

Or do you mean you're trying to access it with another tool? I must admit it's a bit confusing.

If you don't know the URL (my first reaction was: but why wouldn't you know it?), you can simply use the `SVN Repo-browser` of TortoiseSVN since you have that tool (that command is accessible with a right-click on your project folder), it will open a browser and the URL will be visible at the top.

From there, you should still do an update before starting to work.

I would still rather do a new checkout in that case, you don't know what's in the other developer's structure...

Comment: I have never worked on this project before but I would like to take a look at the change history from the last developers but I cant figure out how to access this .svn as it is in www/.svn and the .htaccess directs all requests to www/live/main

Comment: What is `www`, the root directory of the project? Would the `.htaccess` file be part of it too?

Answer (score 0):

if the dir that contains the .svn is on your local machine and if tortoisesvn is installed, you should be able to open a windows explorer, navigate to the folder which contains the .svn directory, right click on the directory (that contains .svn dir) and choose properties. There should be a tab that shows information about which subversion repository the folder is connected to.

Once you determine the url from the dir properties dialog, you should be able to use tortoisesvn browse repository feature (which is also available by right clicking on a directory from within windows explorer). Enter the url (or just the first part of the url) and you should be able to see what else is in the svn repo that is managing the directory.

(Sorry I can't be more specific, I don't have a windows machine handy, but hopefully this should help point you in the right direction)

Comment: Hi Dave; the repo is on a remote server - see my edit plz. thx

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Azlams post I was able to figure out that this repo was actually moved from another portion of the site making it unusable - I will just have to recreate a new one in an easier to access location.

Thanks all for your help!